# Bootstrap 3 Tabs - Accessability

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wai-aria

Are Bootstrap 3 tabs not accessible according to WAI ?

I found the WAI-ARIA specification for tabs keyboard behavior:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/tabs/tabs.html
- https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#tabpanel

which basically says:

> When focus is on a tab element in a horizontal tab list:
>   Left Arrow: moves focus to the previous tab. If focus is on the first tab, moves focus to the last tab. Optionally, activates the newly focused tab (See note below).
>   Right Arrow: Moves focus to the next tab. If focus is on the last tab element, moves focus to the first tab. Optionally, activates the newly focused tab (See note below).

as it seems [Bootstrap 3 tabs documentation samples](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-tabs) fail to meet those requirements.
pressing Left and right arrow keys, have no effect what so ever.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

do i have to implement this behavior by myself ? or am i missing a magic attribute\class that does all the hard work for me ?

Comment: This is sort of an opinion question. I don't think Bootstrap specifically claims to [support WAI-ARAI](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#accessibility)  ("with minimal extra effort") I would think it could be done using role="tablist", role="tab" etc.. on the tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no official support of WAI-ARAI in Bootstrap 3. As mentioned by `@ZimSystem that it could be done using role="tablist", role="tab" etc..`

Solution with JS using attributes `role="tablist", role="tab"`, Try this:

Check Demo [Here](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/aJPVYx?editors=1010)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <h2>Bootstrap 3 Tabs - Accessability</h2></div>

<div id="exTab2" class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Without clearfix</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">Solution</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content ">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="1">
      <h3>Standard tab panel created on bootstrap using nav-tabs</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="2">
      <h3>Notice the gap between the content and tab after applying a background color</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="3">
      <h3>add clearfix to tab-content (see the css)</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  var tabs = $("#exTab2");

  // For each individual tab DIV, set class and aria role attributes, and hide it
  $(tabs).find(".tab-content > div.tab-pane").attr({
    "class": "tabPanel",
    "role": "tabpanel",
    "aria-hidden": "true"
  }).hide();

  // Get the list of tab links
  var tabsList = tabs.find("ul:first").attr({    
    "role": "tablist"
  });

  // For each item in the tabs list...
  $(tabsList).find("li > a").each(
    function(a) {
      var tab = $(this);

      // Create a unique id using the tab link's href
      var tabId = "tab-" + tab.attr("href").slice(1);

      // Assign tab id, aria and tabindex attributes to the tab control, but do not remove the href
      tab.attr({
        "id": tabId,
        "role": "tab",
        "aria-selected": "false",
        "tabindex": "-1"
      }).parent().attr("role", "presentation");

      // Assign aria attribute to the relevant tab panel
      $(tabs).find(".tabPanel").eq(a).attr("aria-labelledby", tabId);

      // Set the click event for each tab link
      tab.click(
        function(e) {
          // Prevent default click event
          e.preventDefault();

          // Change state of previously selected tabList item
          $(tabsList).find("> li.active").removeClass("active").find("> a").attr({
            "aria-selected": "false",
            "tabindex": "-1"
          });

          // Hide previously selected tabPanel
          $(tabs).find(".tabPanel:visible").attr("aria-hidden", "true").hide();

          // Show newly selected tabPanel
          $(tabs).find(".tabPanel").eq(tab.parent().index()).attr("aria-hidden", "false").show();

          // Set state of newly selected tab list item
          tab.attr({
            "aria-selected": "true",
            "tabindex": "0"
          }).parent().addClass("active");
          tab.focus();
        }
      );
    }
  );

  // Set keydown events on tabList item for navigating tabs
  $(tabsList).delegate("a", "keydown",
    function(e) {
      var tab = $(this);
      switch (e.which) {
        case 37:
          //case 38:
          if (tab.parent().prev().length != 0) {
            tab.parent().prev().find("> a").click();
          } else {
            $(tabsList).find("li:last > a").click();
          }
          break;
        case 39:
          //case 40:
          if (tab.parent().next().length != 0) {
            tab.parent().next().find("> a").click();
          } else {
            $(tabsList).find("li:first > a").click();
          }
          break;
      }
    }
  );

  // Show the first tabPanel
  $(tabs).find(".tabPanel:first").attr("aria-hidden", "false").show();

  // Set state for the first tabsList li
  $(tabsList).find("li:first").addClass("active").find(" > a").attr({
    "aria-selected": "true",
    "tabindex": "0"
  });
});
```

Comment: If I'm to use this with Vue.js, is the javascript part going to be inside mounted hook?